# Google's AutoML time series forecasting: understanding data exported to BigQuery during training

Tags: time-series, forecasting, google-cloud-automl

When training a time series forecasting model, I checked the option to "Export test dataset to BigQuery." I'm having a hard time understanding the meaning of the "predicted_on" timestamps that appear in the BigQuery table.

Some info about my model: the granularity is weekly. The context window is 26 weeks, and the forecast horizon is 26 weeks. The 10% test data split also contains exactly 26 weeks of data. In our training data, we have a `submission_week` column which is designated as the "timestamp" column.

- In the BigQuery table, I see the `submission_week` column. It starts
  on 06/05/2022, which is the first date of the 10% test data split.
- The BigQuery table also contains a `predicted_on_submission_week`
  column. (This is the column which I don't understand.)

When I sort the BigQuery table by `submission_week` and then `predicted_on_submission_week`, it looks like this:†

```
predicted_on_submission_week / submission_week
06/05/2022                     06/05/2022
---
06/05/2022                     06/12/2022
06/12/2022                     06/12/2022
---
06/05/2022                     06/19/2022
06/12/2022                     06/19/2022
06/19/2022                     06/19/2022
```

† (Note that for each row above, there actually are multiple rows in the BigQuery table - one for each time series.)

The pattern seen above proceeds until there are at most 6 `predicted_on_submission_week` timestamps for every `submission_week` timestamp.

**My questions:**
What is the meaning of the `predicted_on_submission_week` timestamps? Why are there multiple (at most 6) such timestamps for each `submission_week` timestamp?

(I suspect this may be related to how the context window and forecast horizon are used during training and forecasts as described [here in Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/tabular-data/bp-tabular#how_the_context_window_and_forecast_horizon_are_used_during_training_and_forecasts), but I'm not sure...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regarding my first question (What is the meaning of the `predicted_on_submission_week` timestamps?):**

I've since learned that a `predicted_on` timestamp marks the first date of the forecast horizon of a sliding forecast window.

I found that it's easier to understand and interpret the data when I sort it first by `predicted_on_submission_week` and then by `submission_week`. This way I can view the data in terms of the sliding forecast windows.

**Regarding my second question (Why are there multiple - at most 6 - such timestamps for each submission_week timestamp?):**

I'm not sure, but I did discover the following.

The timestamp format I was using (`mm/dd/yyyy`) is not among the timestamp formats supported by Google according to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/datasets/data-types-tabular#timestamp). I changed my timestamps to `yyyy-mm-dd`. I also ensured that every number in my target column has a decimal (it was previously a mix of integers and decimal numbers). After making these changes, I trained a new model, and examined the data exported to BigQuery.

Now I see that there are 26 weeks of `submission_week` timestamps associated with the first `predicted_on_submission_week` timestamp (2022-06-05). This would suggest that the forecast horizon of the sliding forecast windows is 26 weeks long. This makes more sense to me, given that I set the forecast horizon to 26 weeks when I trained the model. (Also note that the 26th week is the last week of training data - this is relevant to the next point.)

The next `predicted_on_submission_week` timestamp after 2022-06-05 is 2022-06-12. There are 25 weeks of `submission_week` timestamps for this date. This makes sense because now the forecast horizon is extending one week beyond the end of the training data.